# Issues with my output. Did I mess up my RStudio settings?

Tags: r, p-value

When I first downloaded R, every time I ran a t.test or wilcox.test, the output would include not only the p-value but also the mean of the two groups being compared, class-interval etc. I have tried using the summary function but it doesn't provide any extra detail. Now all I get is the following output only:

Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  Change_SIT2 by Exercise condition
W = 1449, p-value = 0.4718
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

Did I mess up my settings?
How can I get the additional information I used to get?

Comment: This sounds like a question for Stack Overflow, as the details of this question are more related to debugging your code.

Comment: This will be an R setting, not an RStudio setting; RStudio is just the IDE. The only configurable option I can see for those functions in their help pages is how NA values are handled. You haven't given an example of the input you're using so check the help pages and examples to make sure you're giving the input in the correct format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the standard output of wilcox.test, nothing wrong there. It sounds like you're missing the t-test output, probably earlier you ran both and now for some reason you only ran wilcox.test. If you consciously run and print both, chances are you get what you're asking for from the t-test output.